# How to manage difference between Rails association and database foreign key constraint?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql

I've come across a subtle difference between Rails 3.2 associations and PostgreSQL foreign keys and I want to be sure I understand the best way to manage it.

Assume a Message class that keeps track of which message it is replying to.  Deleting the "from" message should not delete the rest of the message(s) in the chain, so there is no `:dependent => :destroy` clause.

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  # from_message_id self-reference
  has_many   :from_messages, :foreign_key => "from_message_id", 
             :class_name => "Message", :inverse_of => :from_message
  belongs_to :from_message, 
             :class_name => "Message", :inverse_of => :from_messages

  attr_accessible :from_message_id, subject, body
end
```

Now if I create two linked messages, and delete the first, Rails just reports that it's not there:

```
m1 = Message.create
m2 = Message.new
m2.from_message = m1
m2.save
m1.destroy
m2.from_message
=> nil
```

However if I also add an actual foreign key constraint to the database from my migration:

```
execute "ALTER TABLE messages ADD CONSTRAINT messages_from_message_fk 
         FOREIGN KEY (from_message_id)  REFERENCES messages(id);"
```

then I get a rather nasty abort because the key is still in use:

```
m1 = Message.create
m2 = Message.new
m2.from_message = m1
m2.save
m1.destroy
=> ActiveRecord::InvalidForeignKey: PG::Error: ERROR:  update or delete on table 
"messages" violates foreign key constraint "messages_from_message_fk" on 
table "messages"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(2) is still referenced from table "messages".
```

Are these conclusions correct?

- Rails only uses `has_many` and `belongs_to` to keep track of which fields hold which foreign keys. When deleting a "parent" record, there is no validation that the child record will not be orphaned.
- PostgreSQL with a foreign key constraint requires that all children be "unlinked" from a parent before the parent is deleted. As long as the foreign key is nullable, this can be accomplished by setting the child's foreign key to null before deleting the parent.

In my case, I *want* to allow orphans. Am I better off just forgetting the database constraint, or is there some value in retaining it and unlinking records as their parents are deleted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In my case, I want to allow orphans. Am I better off just forgetting the database constraint, or is there some value in retaining it and unlinking records as their parents are deleted?

In PostgreSQL alter the table by dropping the foreign key constraint and then re-adding it with ON DELETE SET NULL;  In this case the delete will cascade to setting the foreign key to null, allowing orphans,.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'll try to remember that if/when I get back to this project.